B&W horror movie with a man lying fully-clothed in a bath who removes his own eye
As a young child I remember seeing a documentary on television about horror movies, and clips were shown of certain films. These films weren't what you would call "mainstream". 
I remember seeing a clip of a black and white horror film, in which a scene of a man was laid in a bathtub (full clothed). He raised himself and somehow removed one of his eyes (Possibly by flicking it, but I can't quite remember).
I don't remember hearing any speech, nor was the plot properly explained. It may have been a 60's film, as it was a black and white film. The filter of the camera seemed slightly gritty. The man was dressed in a suit, and the room wasn't shown clearly in the particular shot. 
This clip terrified me as a child, and I now wish to know exactly what the film was. 

I might have a hunch, but please provide as many details as possible, even if they seem trivial: Was it in English? Do you know the plot at all? Can you approximate a decade? (And if you really only saw a clip, any kind of descriptive information might help, like what the man or the room looked like.)

I don't remember hearing any speech, nor was the plot properly explained. It may have been a 60's film, as it was a black and white film. The filter of the camera seemed slightly gritty. The man was dressed in a suit, and the room wasn't shown clearly in the particular shot.

Sounds like the ending of the classic horror film Les diaboliques from 1955.

The wife and mistress of a sadistic boarding school headmaster plot to kill him. They drown him in the bathtub and dump the body in the school's filthy swimming pool... but when the pool is drained, the body has disappeared - and subsequent reported sightings of the headmaster slowly drive his 'killers' (and the audience) up the wall with almost unbearable suspense... 

In the end, [HUGE SPOILER] the wife sees the husband's body rising from the bathtub, fully clothed, and she has a heart attack. He then pulls the fake 'zombie' lenses out of his eyes - it was all a ruse that he planned with his mistress to induce exactly that heart attack.




Yes, that is the one. Thank you ever so much.

I highly recommend it, BTW (even with the spoiler)!
